# Make Async Call like API using React Native Typescript With Redux-Toolkit

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I am new to React Native development using redux-toolkit and trying to make api call on button tap. I am using RN v0.71,but getting error

> Blockquote
> "Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<any, void, AsyncThunkConfig>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'.
> "
>
> please find below code :

```
       // store.ts

         import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
         import todoReducer from "../slices/todo/todoSlice"


         export const store = configureStore({
              reducer : {
                todos : todoReducer,
             }
          })

           // Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
             export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
           // Inferred type: {posts: PostsState, comments: CommentsState, users:UsersState}                  
              export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch


  //hooks.ts
        import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-     redux'
         import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from '../store/store'

       // Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
       export const useAppDispatch: () => AppDispatch = useDispatch
       export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector


 ///App.ts

          import { Provider } from "react-redux";
          import { store } from "./src/store/store";
          import Splash from "./src/views/splash/splash";
          import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
          import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
          import { Home } from "./src/views/home/home";

        const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();
        const App = () => {

           return (
        <Provider store = {store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
       <Stack.Navigator>
       <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} 
       options={{headerShown: false}} />
        </Stack.Navigator> 
        </NavigationContainer>
        </Provider>
         )

         }

     export default App;




  ///          todoSlice.ts



               import {Todo} from "../../models/todo"
               import { RootState } from "../../store/store";
               import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
               import { fetchTodos } from "../../actions/fetchTodos";

                type TodosState = {
               // In `status` we will watch
               // if todos are being loaded.
                status: "loading" | "idle";

             // `error` will contain an error message.
               error: string | null;
               list: Todo[];
              };

             const initialState: TodosState = {
                    list: [],
                    error: null,
                    status: "idle",
              };

      export const selectStatus = (state: RootState) =>
     state.todos.status;

     export const todosSlice = createSlice({
name: "todos",
initialState,
reducers: {
  // ...
},

// In `extraReducers` we declare 
// all the actions:
extraReducers: (builder) => {

  // When we send a request,
  // `fetchTodos.pending` is being fired:
  builder.addCase(fetchTodos.pending, (state) => {
    // At that moment,
    // we change status to `loading` 
    // and clear all the previous errors:
    state.status = "loading";
    state.error = null;
  });

  // When a server responses with the data,
  // `fetchTodos.fulfilled` is fired:
  builder.addCase(fetchTodos.fulfilled, 
    (state, { payload }) => {
    // We add all the new todos into the state
    // and change `status` back to `idle`:
    state.list.push(...payload);
    state.status = "idle";
  });

  // When a server responses with an error:
  builder.addCase(fetchTodos.rejected, 
    (state, { payload }) => {
    // We show the error message
    // and change `status` back to `idle` again.
    if (payload) state.error = payload.message;
    state.status = "idle";
     });
    },
  });

   export default todosSlice.reducer


   /// splash.tsx

       import React from "react";
       import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, SafeAreaView, Image } from "react-native";
       import { styles } from "../../utility/styles/styles";
       import { selectStatus } from "../../slices/todo/todoSlice";
       import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
       import { getHomeData } from "../../actions/get_home_json";




     function Splash({ navigation} : {navigation : any}) {

        const status = useSelector(selectStatus);
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const handleClick = () => {dispatch(getHomeData())};



         return (
          <SafeAreaView>
  
          <View >
    
         <Image source={require('../../resources/images/gif/splash.gif')}
         style={styles.image}
         />
  
       <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={ () => handleClick()}>
       <Text> Push Home</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
 
       </View>
     </SafeAreaView>
    
     );
};

export default Splash;
```

**///UPDATE :**
//GetHomeData

```
    import { createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
    import configAEM from "../service/configAEM"
    import API from "../service/core/api";
   import { Alert } from "react-native";



    export const getHomeData =    createAsyncThunk('actions/getHomeData', async () =>{

const response = await API.get(configAEM.apis.home)
// Get the JSON from the response:
const data = await response.json();

// Return result:
return data;
})
```

**`Getting Error on this Line ---> {dispatch(getHomeData())};`**

not able to understand where I am doing wrong. I came across in Typescript
createAsynThunk function not getting type of thunk need to dispatch so used  TypedUseSelectorHook and AppDispatch then in that case got another error i.e

> Blockquote
> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Comment: You need to create an asyncThunk or createApi containing your `getHomeData()` you are importing it from you .json there

Comment: It’s this: `import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux"`. You need to be importing the typed `useAppDispatch` version of the hook from your `hooks.ts` file instead.  You’ve got that part right but you aren’t using it. (Sorry if this is not properly explained but I bet there are other questions that this can be marked as a duplicate of. And also I’m on my phone.  But that’s your problem/solution.)

Comment: @LindaPaiste tried that also in that case as I mentioned getting run time error ---> "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

Comment: Do you get that error if you change the import in `splash.tsx` to `import { useAppDispatch as useDispatch, useAppSelector as useSelector } from “path/to/hooks.ts”;` and keep everything else the same?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I finally found what went wrong :

instead of `const dispatch = useDispatch();` it should be
`const dispatch = useAppDispatch()`; and then I can dispatch asynthunk of   any type